# How can I get the name of voter from the user's table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my current database structure:

```
// users
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Jack   |
| 2  | Peter  |
| 3  | John   |
| 4  | Barman |
| 5  | Ali    |
+----+--------+

// vote
+----------+---------------+
| voter_id | owner_post_id |
+----------+---------------+
| 2        | 3             |
| 4        | 2             |
| 1        | 1             | -- people can vote to its own posts
| 5        | 2             |
| 2        | 2             |
| 3        | 2             |
+----------+---------------+
```

And this is expected output: *(for user `2`)*

```
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
| user_id | user_name | voter_id | voter_name |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 2       | Peter     | 4        | Barman     |
| 2       | Peter     | 5        | Ali        |
| 2       | Peter     | 3        | John       |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

**Note:** generally there should be one more row in the result like this:

```
| 2       | Peter     | 2        | Peter      |
```

But I don't want to get the ones which `user_id` and `voter_id` are the same. How can I do that?

---

My current query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, v.voter_id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN vote v
ON u.id = v.owner_post_id
WHERE u.id = 2 -- for user 2
```

Comment: Left join... where ... is null?

Comment: `AND user_id != voter_id`?

Comment: @Strawberry What? Do I need one more `left join` to get the name of voter?

Comment: Although it's very hard to tell what's being asked here. The title is a completely different question than what's in the post, and the field names in the query don't match the example tables.

Comment: @JJJ What do you mean? Should I add your condition where exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join to the `users` table *twice*, once for each side of the voting relationship.

```
SELECT t2.id AS user_id,
       t2.name AS user_name,
       t3.id AS voter_id,
       t3.name AS voter_name
FROM vote t1
INNER JOIN users t2
    ON t1.owner_post_id = t2.id
INNER JOIN users t3
    ON t1.voter_id = t3.id
WHERE t1.owner_post_id = 2 AND
      t1.voter_id <> t1.owner_post_id
```

Comment: Are you sure about `WHERE t1.owner_post_id = 2 ... ` ?  I guess it should be `WHERE t2.id = 2 AND ...`

Comment: The first join between `vote` and `users` is being done on this condtition: `t1.owner_post_id = t2.id` ... so either check should behave the same.  Actually, I prefer my version because it makes clear which column in the original `vote` table we are using to restrict.

Comment: And for my information, I have one more table named `comment` and it has exactly the same structure like `vote` table. I also need to get the same result for `comment` table too. Can you please tell me how should I use `union all` for them?

Comment: I would probably `UNION` the `vote` and `comment` tables first in a subquery, and then join twice to `users` as I have done above.  You could also select out a computed column for each table in the `UNION` if you wanted to keep track of the source.

Comment: But I won't give a query here.  If you can't figure it out then open a new question.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b436a7c007be9bc862c086224c6805df

Comment: Sorry, `rid` is `voter_id` and `root_id` is `owner_post_id`

Comment: Yes, the basic structure of the query looks right to me.